# How to show dates on x-axis in correct order

Tags: android, achartengine

I have constructed a `TimeChart` graph in my app. But while showing dates on the x-axis it shows a problem. The code I have used while designing a chart using renderer is shown below along with the screenshot. If anyone knows why this problem arises please help me to solve this out.

**Code:**

```
    Calendar pCalendar_FirstDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    int nMinDay = pCalendar_FirstDay.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE);
    Date currentDate = pCalendar_FirstDay.getTime();        
    
    
    renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();     

    //set value for x axis      
    renderer.setChartTitle("Weight / Temperature");
    renderer.setXLabels(15);        
    renderer.setXAxisMin(new Date(currentDate.getYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), nMinDay).getTime());
    renderer.setXAxisMax(currentDate.getTime());
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
               
    //set value for y axis
    renderer.setYLabels(10);  
    renderer.setYTitle("Weight", 0);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(10, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(90, 0);
    renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
    
    renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0,currentDate.getTime(), 10, 90});
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(12);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(12);
    renderer.setPointSize(5f);  
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#5f5f5f"));          
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
```

**The output I got**

[image]

**The output I want is**

[image]

Comment: Hi, i tried ur code to get result as "The output i got" image. but on the x-axis i am getting only the epoch("1366704743") values not the dates like "12-April-2013". Can u help me put here pls .. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

From your APIs, I presume you are using AChartEngine.
How did you build the TimeChart instance?
You should be doing something like this:

```
ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, pattern);
```

where pattern is a date formatting format which you should tweak for getting the desired display.

Comment: Yeh i done it like that only....but can u check my setXAxisMin and setXAxisMax value..becoz in my case initially the data points doesn't contain anything. It will later put by user